# Xray docker image using "jf docker scan DOCKER_IMAGE:TAG --insecure-tls=true" --> error "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I am trying to scan a docker image using "jf docker scan DOCKER_IMAGE:TAG  --insecure-tls=true" but an error "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" is showing up,
Here is the log :

[Warn] (Attempt 1) - Failure occurred while sending GET request to https://THE_URL/api/system/version: Get "https:///api/system/version": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

[Info]  executor timeout after 3 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals

INFORMATION: When I try to send a Curl request from the terminal to the URL it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that JFrog CLI cannot get the certs to trust the connection and fails. I would suggest referring to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#:%7E:text=Authenticating%20with%20Client%20Certificates) first to understand the JFrog CLI's cert validation. Overall, you should simply add the pem file of the cert to the JFROG_CLI_HOME/security/certs directory.